# If the OP posts an answer that says they solved the problem, but doesn't describe how, is that NAA?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-answer, not-an-answer

The OP's answer to his own question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22698796/616460 is "not an answer" in that it doesn't provide an answer to his question that others can see.

My question is: Is this actually a valid "not-an-answer" *flag*? Or is it just worthy of a downvote and a comment requesting more information?

My second question is: If this *is* a "not-an-answer" flag, is this one of those cases that warrants a custom flag with extra information like "Detail: OP stated problem was solved but does not actually state how?" In this particular case, the way the answer is worded, it seems like a moderator who is just looking at the answer in isolation *could* reasonably think it is an answer.

In general, is it appropriate to flag this type answer as not-an-answer / custom flag vs. downvoting vs. leaving it alone?

Comment: It's the answer, which means usually the situation no longer exists or is reproducible, so can be closed as such

Comment: Personally I'd leave a comment asking them to provide more information on the solution. If they don't within a reasonable timeframe (week+, depending on last activity of user), I'd use a custom flag on it.

Comment: @random I see; so you recommend closing the question? What if it's a potentially useful question? I suppose it makes sense to just close it anyways and see if somebody else asks a clearer one some day...?

Comment: @random: following that logic, every question that has been solved can be closed because the problem no longer exists. Just because the answer is subpar, doesn't mean the question is as well.

Comment: There's a difference between "this is solved chickadee banana hotdog" and "I give up, don't bother with this question" @jer

Comment: @random How does that difference relate back to the question I linked to above? It seems like the answer is a "this is solved chickadee banana hotdog" (which we will now refer to as CBH answers)?

Comment: "It was in the config file" is something that cannot be reproduced, if they leave the answer as that, then yes, the question should be closed to fit because it will help no one and will bring in searchers that will be frustrated their question is closed as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @gnat At least spell your new tags right.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's an answer of low quality, but it is a borderline case which I would allow.

On the one hand there is an answer like this:

> Nevermind, I fixed it myself

and on the other hand there is this:

> Found it! Apparantly I forgot to set `Awesomeness` to `true`.

The first one is not useful to any future reader at all and should not be considered an answer; the latter is obviously a good answer.

The answer we're talking about here is

> Looks like I forgot to configure my `Awesomeness`.

This answer is still useful to future readers (they know it has something to do with their `Awesomeness`), even though it does not explicitly say what the solution is.

I always leave a comment in cases like this to ask the user to expand on it.

If he does: problem solved.
If he doesn't: you've done all you could, maybe someone comes along later who solved that same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike situations where a user other than the OP posts a similar answer, I wouldn't flag as "not an answer" or "very low quality". Without it, it's unclear to others what part was "no longer reproducible" if it was closed as such, and if not closed, people wouldn't know that the issue has already been solved. I also don't think it's suitable to convert to a comment, as these are temporary and it's not possible to accept comments.

Comment: Indeed, hasty flaggers who succeed in getting the asker's own answer removed generally leave behind a question that will then *never* have an accepted answer.